# PHP - Search for Domain Name Availability

Tags: php, dns

I guys.

I would like to know how to build on of those Domain Name Availability search that many hosting companies have.

I've looked around SO and found a Question about it, but the guy that asked it used a class for the hole job, and he didn't posted its code or referred any source.

Can somebody give me a hand how to build one for a website I'm building, using PHP of course.

Thanks.

Comment: Building your own involves a lot complexity, as there are many different whois servers. You can use my [Whois API](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) to hide that complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pretty straight forward process as you are sending a request to whois-servers.net and evaluating the response.  Check out the Bulk Availability Script at http://www.dnmedia.com/bulk_availability.php.  It should do exactly what you need.

Check out the full article at http://dnmedia.com/the-power-of-whois/ which also has code for getting the domain owner's contact details.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a good place to start: [Creating a domain checker](http://www.phptoys.com/e107_plugins/content/content.php?content.38)